# Open ports for sealers in POA

Tags: poa, clique, geth-clique

Should sealers have open TCP/UDP ports that allow other nodes to connect when running a clique blockchain?

Edit:

**In other words**: Is it mandatory for sealer nodes to accept incoming connections on the peer communication and discovery port?

Comment: By default,  **TCP/30303** and **UDP/30301** are used for peer communication and peer discovery respectively if I'm not wrong. Assuming that you are on default settings, you'd need them both.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that these ports are used for peer communication, but my question is if it is mandatory to allow connections to the sealer nodes.

Comment: Well I guess it's not but if you want to add any other (non sealer) node how would they be able to sync to the blockchain if the sealers do not allow connection ?

Comment: There are bootstrap nodes where new nodes can connect to.

Comment: No, bootstrap nodes are just used to speedup peer discovery, they do not allow syncing.